# Is it Possible to Not Log In?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

I got logged out of meta at about 17:02, and from SO at about 17:20 local time. I was then immediately logged back in.

I was intrigued by the new login UI, and wanted to play with it. However, as soon as I click "log out", I get logged back in again!

Is there a way to just not be logged in? Do I need to use a different computer, or to delete cookies?

Alternatively, did I miss the announcement or blog post about this new feature?

---

I just tried again, this time clicking the "Log out Everywhere" button. It didn't even log me out, as far as I could see. After two or three more random clicks, I found myself logged out, and I stayed logged out. This included, BTW, a 404 error on a URL with a `?returnUrl=%2f` or something like that.

Pretty new UI, but you've god a few bugs here.

Comment: Just happened to me, too.  I must have missed the same (lack of?) announcement.

Comment: @tvanfosson: yeah, it's a talent I need to better develop on these sites: the ability to know what has not been announced.

Comment: The log out worked for me. I just hit `[Log out]`... then `[Log out everywhere]`... then it logged me back in... then I hit `[Log out]` twice in the upper menu bar........... and then it really truly logged me out.... I could only post this comment after logging back in.

Comment: @Kevin: norepro? Peter Ajtai is reporting the same thing.

Comment: Tagging these are non-repro is really not useful in these cases, as it is a real issue, the "I got logged out" threads that popup now and again are just from those with enough motivation to post it, I imagine many more (including myself) are actually experiencing the issue.  It is real, though seemingly sporadic, immediately tagging it no-repro seems not at all helpful.  If you're ignoring it that's fine, but *tag* it that way, "status-ignored", saying you can't repro when many people are reporting the issue is a lack of effort, *say* you don't have time, it's understandable, don't dismiss it.

Comment: I just tried logging out again. The first time it worked as it was supposed to. The second time I had to hit log out 1 additional time after the `[Log out everywhere]` button (Chrome). I'm sure it can be reproduced if one tries several times.

Comment: @nick if you can give us repro steps I can reproduce, we won't tag it [no-repro] -- otherwise, well, that's what it is.

Comment: @Jeff: this was flagged as no-repro very soon after it was posted. That suggests that little effort was made to reproduce it.

Comment: @john neither Kevin nor I could repro this in Firefox.

Comment: @Jeff: correct me if my math is wrong, but it would appear that you attempted to reproduce for no more than 12 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your problem is that you are not refreshing your browser's cache.

Try pressing `Shift` + `F5` after logging out and see if that doesn't help

Comment: there are Chrome-specific issues where Chrome will show you a cached page of you being "logged in" after you've logged out, btw.

Comment: @Jeff - I don't believe it's Chrome specific, open Chrome, IE, Firefox (6, 8 and 4 here), login with each, click "Log Out Everywhere", I did this in IE...the other 2 browsers remain unaffected, even with a hard refresh I can post comments, etc...still logged in.

Comment: @nick so you mean different browsers SIMULTANEOUSLY? That's fine, but that is not at all what John was discussing.

Comment: @Jeff - I can't repro it reliably, logging in and out in IE seems to be the best method to repro the issue specific to this question...but IE also has the worst tools for debugging it, I'll take a look in fiddler tomorrow and see if I can identify what's different.  It *seems* to be a timing issue with the global auth kicking in or finishing after the local logoff completes, but that's a guess at this point, will need to look at the requests a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, if you're having difficulties, be sure to use **LOG OUT EVERYWHERE** to clear global auth.

[image]

Comment: Jeff, FYI, more than "Log Out Everywhere" is required. See Peter Ajtai's comment above - a fair amount of extra clicks were needed before it decided we were really logged out.